# update the content of an input field by javascript

Tags: javascript

I change the content of an input field by a javascript function like this:

```
document.forms.nameOfForm.nameOfField.value = document.getElementById('listuser').textContent;
```

until now there is no problem.

I have to set this field as `readonly="true"` because it's a date choosen by the calendar so the function will not be executed.  I ask how to force the updating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `readonly` via JavaScript to `false`, update the field, and set `readonly` back to `true`.